# different combinations for at least four objects from 3 identical, 4 identical and 5 identical

Tags: combinatorics

If you have 3 identical chocolates, 4 identical chips and 5 identical cookies. How many different combinations of these items can you have if you must choose at least 4.

My answer to the question was find the total combinations minus all cases with less than 4 objects.

4*5*6= total combos

0 objects= 1
1 object=3C1
2 different= 3C2
2 same=3C1
3 different=3C3
3 same= 3C1
2 alike 1 different= 3C1*2C2

So total combos with 4 or greater objects= 4*5*6-1-3C1-3C2-3C1-3C3-3C1-3C1*2C2= 103

But the answer is supposed to be 100 not 103.
Does anyone see any mistakes that I made?

Comment: There are 6 ways to choose 2 alike 1 different instead of 3, namely {aab, aac, bba, bbc, cca, ccb} if we let a be chocolate, b be chip and c be cookie. I guess the 2C2 part is where you confused the type you choose with the number of things you choose. It is supposed to be 2C1.

Comment: You're right! Thank you, that would have kept me up all night.